# The product of discrete two-point spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the product of the continuum discrete two-point spaces. Show that not every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

We can show that $X$ is compact by the Tikhonov theorem. And I suppose $X$ must be homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Comment: Are "colons" discrete two-point spaces? I'd not heard "colon" as name for a topological space...

Comment: No, the Cantor set is homeomorphic to a product of *countably* many copies of $\{ 0, 1 \}$.  In particular, $X$ has the wrong cardinality $2^c$ to be homeomorphic to the Cantor set which has cardinality $c$.

Comment: Yes, you're right about colons. I am sorry. I fixed.

Comment: I explained the same idea as @DanielSchepler in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1558796/4280)

Comment: $X$ is called a "Cantor cube", as are all spaces of the form $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is a cardinal number. Only for $\kappa$ countable do we get a homeomorphic space to the standard Cantor set in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you should presumably know that in a product space, a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x$ if and only if $x_n(i) \to x(i)$ pointwise for each $i$ in the index set of the family.  So, the goal is to produce a sequence such that after taking any subsequence, you still have oscillation of values of $x_n$ at some $i$.

So, to come up with a concrete example, let's identify the index set with $P(\mathbb{N})$, the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.  Then consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements of $P(\mathbb{N}) \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ defined by:
$$x_n(S) = \begin{cases} 1, & n \in S \\ 0, & n \notin S. \end{cases}$$
Now, suppose you have a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ of this sequence.  Your goal from here will be to find an index $S \in P(\mathbb{N})$ such that $x_{n_k}(S)$ is not eventually constant, and therefore the subsequence cannot have a limit because $x_{n_k}(S)$ does not have a limit.

Comment: Pictorially, if you instead use the interval $[0,1]$ as the index set, then the sequence roughly corresponds to the indicator functions of $[0, 1/2]$, $[0, 1/4] \cup [1/2, 3/4]$, $[0, 1/8] \cup [1/4, 3/8] \cup [1/2, 5/8] \cup [3/4, 7/8]$, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Can we take as the set S a Cantor set?

Comment: A Cantor set isn't an element of $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Yes, my fault. Need to think more

Comment: I am sorry, but what do we call the limit of the sequence from the zeroes and the units?

Comment: A sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq \{ 0, 1 \}$ converges to $L \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ if and only if $x_n = L$ for sufficiently large $n$.  (Pretty much the same statement is true for convergence of sequences in any discrete space.)  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Maybe I'm dull, but from compactness follows sequential compactness. So every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Compactness only implies sequential compactness for metric spaces, while $\{ 0, 1 \}^c$ is not metrizable.

Comment: @Shorty12319 No, in general spaces compactness does **not** imply sequential compactness. $\{0,1\}^\mathfrak{c}$ is one of the counterexamples, as is $\beta \omega$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Even for $X$ sequential (much weaker than metric) we get that compactness implies sequential compactness.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, can you explain please why $ \{ 0, 1 \}^c$  is one of the counterexamples? I thought it is metrizable.