# Show that $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is not sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, sequence-of-function

> Show that $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is not sequentially compact

Obviously, it is taken with the product topology of the subspace topologies (which are, in fact, discrete).

Now, the elements are tuples of $0$'s and $1$'s with $[0,1]$ as the indexing set. For a sequence to converge in this topology, for any collection of finite indices, $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the terms of the sequence match the limit in those indices after that $m$. I cannot go any further.

Hints are welcome rather than complete answers.

Comment: A slight variation on the argument by @RobertZ below is given in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1558796/4280) . The size of the domain $I$ or $[0,1]$ is the same so the spaces are homeomorphic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Product space that is compact, but isn't sequentially compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558448/product-space-that-is-compact-but-isnt-sequentially-compact)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x\in [0,1]$ consider its unique binary expansion that has not an infinite tail of ones and let $f_n(x)$ be the $n$-th binary digit of $x$. Therefore
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{2^n}.$$
Does the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ have a convergent subsequence in $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$?

The answer is no. Take any subsequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and consider the point
$x=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n_{2j}}}\in [0,1].$
Then $f_{n_k}(x)=1$  when $k$ is even and $f_{n_k}(x)=0$ otherwise, which implies that the sequence $(f_{n_k}(x))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\{0,1\}$ is not convergent and therefore $(f_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent in $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: What is the meaning of "$(f_n)_n$"?

Comment: @EricTowers For each $n$, $f_n$ is an element of a specific sequence. $(f_n)_n$ is that sequence. It's somewhat common notation, although I don't use it much myself.

Comment: @EricTowers It is the sequence of $f_n$ where $f_n$ is a tuple/function that takes the $n$th binary digit in the expansion of the index.

Comment: $f_n(x)$ is a bit.  $f_n$ is a function.  $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of functions indexed by the naturals, so is very much not an element of $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$.  Perhaps you mean $(f_n(x))_x$?

Comment: @EricTowers $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is the set of functions $f:[0,1]\to \{0,1\}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RobertZ : Sure.  But $(f_n)_n$ is not indexed by $[0,1]$.

Comment: $(f_n)_n$ is the sequence of $f_n$ indexed by $n$. Do you prefer the notation $\{f_n\}_n$ ?

Comment: You already established that $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and have given no map $\Bbb{N} \rightarrow [0,1]$, so you have written $(f_n(?))_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$, which is not a $[0,1]$-indexed sequence.  Also, relevant to the current edit: sets don't have subsequences.

Comment: Why should I give a map $\Bbb{N} \rightarrow [0,1]$? A sequence in $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to \{0,1\}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Each of the $f_n$ are elements of $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$. Which is to say, each $f_n$ is a $[0,1]$-indexed sequence (thought of as a function). Then we have a sequence of those, indexed by $n\in \Bbb N$, because we want to talk about sequential compactness of $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: "$(f_n)_n$" is **not** indexed by a variable ranging over $[0,1]$.  You have established that $n$ ranges over $\Bbb{N}$.  $\Bbb{N} \neq [0,1]$, but you have now repeatedly claimed that $\Bbb{N} = [0,1]$.

Comment: @EricTowers $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is a space of $[0,1]$-indexed sequences. We are looking at $\Bbb N$-indexed sequences in that space, thus a sequence of sequences. Robert's presentation of his such sequence makes perfect sense.

Comment: I have no confusion about the *meaning* of the second "$n$" in $(f_n)_n$ it indicates which of the two symbols in parentheses is the index.  Apparently, it's the subscript on $f$ which is already established to only range over $\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes. Because _each $f_n$ itself_ is a $[0,1]$-indexed sequence, thought of as a function.

Comment: Where does this uncountable index appear in "$f_n$"?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}\times [0,1]\ni (n,x)\to f_n(x)\in\{0,1\}$

Comment: @EricTowers It doesn't. Because when you write the name of a function (in this case $f_n$ for all the various $n$), you usually don't write the variable name.

Comment: So the correct notation is $(f_n(x))_x$, because $x$ actually *can* range over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @EricTowers No, the correct notation is $(f_n)_n$, because you usually don't write the variable when you write the name of a function. Writing $f_n(x)$ implies that you're talking about the function value for a specific $x$, which would make $(f_n(x))_n$ a $\Bbb N$-indexed sequence in $\{0,1\}$, not $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: There is nothing in "$f_n$" that can take any value in $[0,1]$.  Consquently, you have not written a sequence indexed by $[0,1]$, which is what you keep saying you have written.

Comment: @EricTowers It's a function. You usually don't write a variable when you write the name of a function. How many times do I have to repeat myself?

Comment: Until you actually write an expression indexed by a variable that can range over $[0,1]$ so that can actually be an element of the set it is supposed to be.

Comment: Insisting that the correct notation is $(f_n(x))_x$ is like insisting that the correct way to write a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ is $(x_n(i))_i$.

Comment: "$(f_n)_n$" is literally indexed by $n$.  $n$ does not range over $[0,1]$.  You seem to be writing an element of $\Bbb{R}^n$ in the form $(x_i)_{i \in \{0,1\}}$.

Comment: Let's come at this from the other side.  What's the cardinality of what you have currently written, "$\{f_n\}_n$"?  Are there nearly enough things in that set to have an injection from $[0,1]$?

Comment: A sequence in ANY topological space is indexed by natural numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence Here we have a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: An element of $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is indexed by $[0,1]$.

Comment: The term "sequence" is related  that the fact that the space $X=\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is not "sequentially" compact https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space

Comment: An element $x$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is a collection of members of $\mathbb R$ indexed by members of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. A sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ is written as $(x_n)_n$. Similarly, an element $f$ of $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is a collection if members of $\{0,1\}$ indexed by members of $[0,1]$. A sequence in $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is written as $(f_n)_n$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist : "A sequence $(x_n)_n$" written after $n$ has already been bound as the dimension of the space is gibberish.

Comment: I give up.  Your decision to replace sequences with sets reduces readability, but that is not my main concern.  Your argument is unintelligible to me after 45 minutes of trying to find a way to interpret the types to be sensible.  Repeatedly claiming that a countable index somehow ranges over $[0,1]$ is not something I will ever accept.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should have said $\mathbb R^k$. However, I’m certain Robert Z did not at all claim that a countable index ranges over $[0,1]$. I’m sorry the explanations here have not been sufficient. However, this truly is a standard piece of notation, so I’m not sure why you think it’s mistaken.

Comment: @EricTowers We're not replacing sequences with sets. We're replacing (the $[0,1]$-indexed) sequences with functions. In fact, I personally read $X^Y$ for sets $X, Y$ first and foremost as a set of functions, not of sequences. So a _sequence_ in $X^Y$ is a sequence of functions, and writing that sequence as $(f_n)_n$ is completely natural.