# Uncountable product of T1 sequentially compact spaces is never sequentially compact (continuum hypothesis)

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How to prove the statement:

*Assuming the continuum hypothesis, the product of any uncountable family of $T_1$ spaces, each having more than one point, is never sequentially compact.*

The statement appears in General Topology by Stephen Willard, exercise 17G.6.

My attempt was along the lines of trying to use the sequential compactness (*any sequence  of points in the space has a convergent subsequence whose limit is in it*) of the space defined to build a set that would violate the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis). But I could not find the right construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the structural overview of a proof, I urge you to fill in all details:

**Step 1:** Use what is given. So we have
$$ X=\prod _{i\in I}X_i$$
where each $X_i$ has at least two distinct points $a_i$ and $b_i$.
Also $I$ is uncountable means that $I$ is not smaler than $\Bbb R$, or equivalently not smaller than $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$. That is, there exists an *onto* map $f\colon I\to \mathcal P(\Bbb N)$.

**Step 2:** Construct a tricky sequence $(x^{(n)})_{n\in \Bbb N}$ from the above. That is, use $f$ and the $a_i,b_i$ - but how? Well, we can let $x^{(n)}_i=a_i$ or $=b_i$ depending on whether or not $n\in f(i)$!

**Step 3:** Finish, i.e., for every subsequence $(x^{(n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and every point $c\in X$, show that $x^{(n_k}\not \to c$.

Comment: A subsequence of a product space fails to converge iff. it fails to converge pointwise as a function on one of the components. However, if I let any such failure-component be $i\in I$, then it is entirely possible for a subsequence to converge pointwise since if $f(i)$ is finite, then I can say $x_i\to b_i\because n\notin f(i)$ for large $n$, and if $f(i)$ is infinite then it is entirely possible to say either $x_i\to a_i\because n\in f(i)$ or $x_i\to b_i$. If I then bring in other indices, I cannot reach a contradiction. Could you help me with the argument?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1558796/4280) I show that $P:=\{0,1\}^{2^{\Bbb N}}$ is not sequentially compact, using a diagonalisation argument (this holds in plain ZFC, so "absolutely").

If CH holds and $I$ is uncountable and $X_i, i \in I$ is a family of $T_1$ spaces having more than one point, we have that $P$ is homeomorphic to a  closed subspace of $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$. (CH is needed to get $|I| \ge \mathfrak{c}= |2^{\aleph_0}|$ from $I$ being merely uncountable) So if the latter *were* sequentially compact so would $P$ be, quod non.

FYI: there are models of ZFC where $[0,1]^{\aleph_1}$ *is* sequentially compact. See the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology for more on this. This shows CH is really needed.

This is the essence of the argument.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does MA imply that products of $<\mathfrak c$ sequentially compact spaces is sequentially compact? I can sort of see how it would imply that every sequence has a convergent subnet, but I'm not sure whether that is enough to extract an actual sequence.

Comment: @tomasz IIRC it does. Check the Handbook maybe. It’s related to the tower number cardinal invariant.

Comment: @tomasz in Fremlin's very good book "Consequences of Martin's Axiom" 24B says that a product of $< \mathfrak{p}$ sequentially compact spaces is sequentially compact. And MA implies that $\mathfrak{c}=\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have guessed Fremlin would have said something about that.

Comment: Would your $P$ have cardinality $\aleph_2$? (In CH)

Comment: @FShrike $P$ has size $2^{\mathfrak{c}}  = 2^{\aleph_1} \ge \aleph_2$ under CH. No more can be said; it could be $\aleph_{42}$ e.g. CH is not enough to say that.

Comment: Ah my apologies. I believe I meant GCH, the generalised continuum hypothesis!

Comment: @FShrike Under GCH yes, we get $\aleph_2$. Why do you care?

Comment: I don't know much set theory, so I was just checking as a student. My mistake earlier revealed exactly my inexperience.  Thank you! Your answers have helped me a good deal with my topology studies recently. Your answer is fundamentally the same I think as Hagen von Eitzen's, but I could not follow it one bit, but yours is clear.